# Show that : $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^{-3} \sum_{k=1}^{n} E|X_{k}|^{2} I(|X_{k}| \leq n) \leq c \sum_{k=1}^{n} E|X_{k}|^{p} \sum_{n=k}^{\infty} n^{-1-p}$

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, law-of-large-numbers

I was trying to add some details to a result concerning the strong law of large numbers for pairwise independent random variables : here's what I've done :

Let $\epsilon > 0,1<p<2, \, (X_i)_{i\geq1}$ be a sequence of identically distributed and pairwise (not mutually!) independent random variables :

\begin{multline*} P\left \{\left|\sum_{k=1}^n (X_k-EX_k) \right|>\varepsilon n\right\} = P\left \{\left|\sum_{k=1}^n (X_k-EX_k) \right|>\varepsilon n, \, \exists k \, : |X_k| >n \right \} \\ + P\left \{\left|\sum_{k=1}^n (X_k-EX_k) \right|>\varepsilon n, \, \forall k \, : |X_k|\leq n \right\} \\ \leq   P\left \{ \exists k \, : |X_k| >n \right \} + P\left \{\left|\sum_{k=1}^n (X_k-EX_k)I(|X_k| \leq n)  \right|>\varepsilon n, \, \forall k \, : |X_k|\leq n \right\} \\  \leq   P\left \{ \bigcup_{k = 1}^{n}|X_k| >n \right \} + P\left \{\left|\sum_{k=1}^n (X_k-EX_k)I(|X_k| \leq n)  \right|>\varepsilon n \right\} \\ \leq   \sum_{k = 1} ^{n} P\left \{|X_k| >n \right \} + P\left \{\left|\sum_{k=1}^n (X_k-EX_k)I(|X_k| \leq n)  \right|>\varepsilon n / 2 \right\}  \end{multline*}

and so by the above inequality, Markov's inequality, the triangular inequality and using the fact that the $X_k's$ are pairwise independent we get :

\begin{multline*}
  \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}n^{-1} P \left \{\left|\sum_{k=1}^n (X_k-EX_k) \right|>\varepsilon n\right\}  \leq     \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}n^{-1} \sum_{k = 1} ^{n} P\left \{|X_k| >n \right \}  \\ +   \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}n^{-1} P\left \{\left|\sum_{k=1}^n (X_k-EX_k)I(|X_k| \leq n)  \right|>\varepsilon n / 2 \right\} \\ \leq  \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}n^{-1} \sum_{k = 1} ^{n} n^{-p} E|X_k|^p +   \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}n^{-1} \frac{4n^{-2}}{\varepsilon^2}( E \sum_{k = 1} ^{n} \left|(X_k-EX_k)I(|X_k| \leq n)   \right|^2 + 0) \\ \leq  \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}n^{-1-p} \sum_{k = 1} ^{n}  E|X_k|^p +   c \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}n^{-3} \sum_{k = 1} ^{n} E \left|X_k \right|^2 I(|X_k| \leq n) \\  
  \end{multline*}

now all I need to reach the conclusion in the paper is to show that : $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}n^{-3} \sum_{k = 1} ^{n} E \left|X_k \right|^2 I(|X_k| \leq n) \leq c \sum_{k = 1} ^{n} E \left|X_k \right|^p \sum_{n =k}^{\infty}n^{-1-p} $

Comment: What is the range of $p$? Assuming $p < 2$, you can upper bound $\mathbb{E}[|X_k|^2] I(|X_k| \leq n) \leq \mathbb{E}[|X_k|^p] n^{2 - p}$. On rearranging the sums I believe you should get your required result.

Comment: @sudeep5221 indeed, 1<p<2